# Custom Artisan Command to execute multiple commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Is there a way to execute some artisan commands, using custom artisan command, like I want to make a custom command called:

```
$ php artisan project:init
```

which will execute some commands like `php artisan migrate:refresh` and `php artisan db:seed` and `php artisan config:clear`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hello, Can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 15):

There is 2 way to group commands or call it from another command.

Variant 1:
Create new Console Command in `routes/console.php` .
**routes/console.php**

```
Artisan::command('project:init', function () {
    Artisan::call('migrate:refresh', []); // optional arguments
    Artisan::call('db:seed');
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
})->describe('Running commands');
```

Variant 2:
According to docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands

Create new command using command line:

```sh
$ php artisan make:command ProjectInit --command project:init
```

This will create new file: `App\Console\Commands\ProjectInit`

In that `ProjectInit` class's `handle` method you can call another commands:

```
public function handle(){
  $this->call('migrate:refresh', []); // optional arguments
  $this->call('db:seed');
  $this->call('config:clear');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i've made the command by reading the docs as you've mentioned and it worked after i've called those commands as the docs mentioned 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands

Comment: Glad to help you, please close question by accepting this answer. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can call console commands programmatically

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands

I've used it on a number of occasions where i've wanted to bundle commands together. For example:

```
$this->call('custom:command1', [
    '--argument1' => 'foo',
]);

$this->call('custom:command2', [
    '--argument1' => 'bar',
]);
```

Comment: Glad i could help :)