# Laravel Schedule Command in OnSuccess not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7, cron-task

I am trying to chaing 4 commands one after another
Example:

```
  $schedule->command('test1')->everyMinute()->onSuccess(function () use($schedule){
            $schedule->call('test2')->onSuccess(function () use($schedule){
                $schedule->call('test3')->onSuccess(function () use($schedule){
                   $schedule->call('test4');
                });
            });
        });
```

But Only the first command gets executed.
Even if i use `command` instead of `call` inside the closures it does not work.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you calling the `$scheduler` when you should refer to the Kernel, using `$this->call()` instead of `$schedule`? I think it does not run, because the scheduler needs to have instruction on when to run the command exactly.

Comment: @EricLandheer $this->call() I can't chain it further as there are 4 commands which need to run one after another

Comment: Look at this question, Explains how to call one command from another. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872499/custom-artisan-command-to-execute-multiple-commands/61872714

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to the `Kernel` using `$this` instead of passing the scheduler. The scheduler expects you to specify the [frequency options](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options). With the `Kernel` you can use the  `$this->call()` function to run additional commands. Unfortunately, `call()` does not have `hooks` like `onSuccess`.

Instead, if you want to chain more than one command `onSuccess()` you should consider [calling the command from another command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands).