# How to combine 2 function in php?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, static, statamic

How can I combine 2 functions in PHP?

I have 2 functions,

function #1

```
public function cache()
{
    $command = 'clear:cache';

    try {
        Artisan::call($command);
        $call = trim(Artisan::output());
        return back()->with('success', $call);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Problem running command: ' . $command);
        return back()->withErrors('error', ' There was a problem' . $e);
    }
}
```

function #2

```
public function staticCache()
{
    $command = 'clear:static';

    try {
        Artisan::call($command);
        $call = trim(Artisan::output());
        return back()->with('success', $call);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Problem running command: ' . $command);
        return back()->withErrors('error', ' There was a problem' . $e);
    }
}
```

I've tried this

```
public function cache()
{
    $commandClearCache = 'clear:cache';
    $commandClearStatic = 'clear:static';

    try {
        Artisan::call($commandClearCache, $commandClearStatic);
        $call = trim(Artisan::output());
        return back()->with('success', $call);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Problem running command: ' . $command);
        return back()->withErrors('error', ' There was a problem' . $e);
    }
}
```

But give me an error message: "**Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::call() must be of the type array, string given, called in /usr/share/nginx/html/statamic/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 217**"

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli thats not what the error said, cause the error references to the second argument not the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first function is the same as the result of your tries, I think you copied the wrong function here. Nevertheless the second parameter of the Artisan::call function is for options not for a second Command.

You can either execute the Artisan::call function twice, one for each command you want to call like done here [Custom Artisan Command to execute multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872499/custom-artisan-command-to-execute-multiple-commands). Or use Queueing https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#queueing-artisan-commands.

```php
public function cache()
{
    $commands = ['clear:cache', 'clear:static'];
    $callResponse = '';

    foreach ($commands as $command) {
        try {
            Artisan::call($command);
            $callResponse .= trim(Artisan::output()) . PHP_EOL;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Problem running command: ' . $command);
            return back()->withErrors('error', ' There was a problem' . $e);
        }

        return back()->with('success', $callResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've wrong copying function #1. I have edited the code above.

Comment: gave you the example how to execute both

Comment: This won't work as you'll just return after executing the first, however the loop itself is a good suggestion.

Comment: @Yinci absolutely, my bad, fixed it